# Split multi label data based on number of classes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am quite new to Matlab. I have a matrix of training features of size 2561x108 and a set of corresponding labels 2561x1 with 15 distinct classes labelled from 1 to 15. What I want to understand is how to split the data so that I have only certain number of instances say 50 per class and the rest is test set? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Last sentence should be "the rest is the test set?". Features are the columns so to say

Comment: Thank for the edit. Yes features are columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each class, you could use the [`find` function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) (or the [`strncmp`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strncmp.html)  if labels are strings). You can isolate any elements which are classed by given labels this way. It will return the index of such elements which you can use then to extract from the main 2561x108 matrix.

for example if the output (say =x) gives you 1:50, then `x=1:50`, using `Label1 = mainMatrix(class1,x)` will create a datastructure called `Labe1` which consists of the 50 elements belonging to `class1`